# what data type is returned by re.search(pattern, stringOfText) in Python? An int or string?

Tags: python, string, python-re

Consider the following code below. I was told that if regExMagic() doesn't find a match for Lucy in the string of text, it returns "None" to regExMagic(). Since "None" is already a string why do we still need to wrap regExMagic() in a str() in the comparison below?

What's interesting is when I removed str() it executed only the else statement (not seen here) for each line (image below) and it didn't throw any TypeError exception that I'm trying to compare 2 different types assuming an int could have been returned to regExMagic(). But since only the else got executed then it probably didn't even bother throwing an exception?

So my main question is why do we need to include str() in this case even though "None" gets returned as I was told to regExMagic()?

Am I missing something here?

```
import re

def regExMagic(pattern, string):
    objectMatch = re.search(pattern, string)
    return objectMatch

def readingLinesWithRegEx():

    try:
        with open('people.txt') as file_object:
            contents = file_object.readlines()

            for line in contents:
                pattern = 'HEllo$'

                if str(regExMagic(pattern, line)) == "None":
                    print(line)
```

Comment: That's easy to find out: `print(type(your_variable))`

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Here, you posted a question which you should have answered yourself, simply by examining the type of the return value.

Comment: print(type(regExMagic(pattern, line))) revealed 'NoneType' which explains why str() must be used to be able to compare it to "None". Thanks for clarifying Barmar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the value `None` (whose type is `NoneType`), not the string `"None"`. So if you want to compare it with a string you have to convert it.

But it's simpler to just compare it directly without converting:

```
if regExMagic(pattern, line) is None:
    print(line)
```

You can also just test the truth value, since any other value it returns will be a non-falsey object. So just write:

```
if not regExMagic(pattern, line):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks!! all makes sense now. I got confused about the NoneType since I never worked with it before.

Comment: It's similar to `null` in PHP and JavaScript.